# Concerning the homotopy long exact sequence of a pair

Tags: homotopy-theory

Recall that for a pair $(X,A)$, there is the following long exact sequence
$\cdots \longrightarrow \pi_2 (A)\longrightarrow \pi_2 (X)\longrightarrow    \pi_2 (X,A)\longrightarrow \pi_1 (A)\longrightarrow \pi_1 (X)\longrightarrow \pi_1 (X,A).$
Also, I know that $\pi_1 (A)$ acts on $\pi_n (X,A)$ and $\pi_n (X)$ for all $n$.
 My question is that     :

"is the above long exact sequence a sequence of  $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (A)]$-modules and $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (A)]$-homomorphisms?

Could you help me to understand it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the action, all terms are $\Bbb Z[\pi_1(A)]$-modules. Remains the question if the arrows are $\Bbb Z[\pi_1(A)]$-module-homomorphisms, i.e., are they compatible with the action? (after that, exactness itself is no problem because images and kernels remain "the same" when switching to  $\Bbb Z[\pi_1(A)]$-modules)

Comment: Yes. My question is that.

Comment: Yes exactly. It is enough to show that every $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism in the above long exact sequence is $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (A)]$-homomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact, it is clear from the definitions that $\pi_1 (A)$ acts on the
whole long exact sequence of homotopy groups for $(X,A)$, the action commuting
with the various maps in the sequence. (see Hatcher's book, p. 345).

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for your answer.